# CI4 Form with jQuery refresh instead of submitting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have form with autocomplete using jQuery. jQuery works fine, it does its job filling the form but whenever i submit the form after using the autocompletion, it doesn't call proper function in controller. All it does is refresh the page.

I've tried checking if it enters any other functions in my controller and it doesn't.

The form works perfectly fine when i remove the jQuery. With jQuery it never works when I use autocompletion and it also sometimes does the same refresh thing even if I fill the form myself.

To me it looks like jQuery makes my form do some other thing than it should after clicking submit button but I don't know why and how to fix that.

I dont think that View and Controller files matter that much because they work fine without jQuery so I'm gonna paste only jQuery here, because i believe that it might be the problem.

jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#autocompleteChip').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            var csrfName = $('.txt_csrftoken').attr('name');
            var csrfHash = $('.txt_csrftoken').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "<?= site_url('scan/getChipNumbers') ?>",
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    search: request.term,
                    [csrfName]: csrfHash
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.txt_csrftoken').val(data.token);
                    response(data.data);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#autocompleteChip').val(ui.item.label);
            $('#autocompleteDogName').val(ui.item.dogName);
            $('#autocompleteBreed').val(ui.item.breed);
            $('#autocompleteBirthyear').val(ui.item.birthyear);
            $('#autocompleteEmail').val(ui.item.owner_email);
            $('#autocompleteSex').val(ui.item.sex);


            return false;
        },
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $('#autocompleteChip').val(ui.item.label);
            $('#autocompleteDogName').val(ui.item.dogName);
            $('#autocompleteBreed').val(ui.item.breed);
            $('#autocompleteBirthyear').val(ui.item.birthyear);
            $('#autocompleteEmail').val(ui.item.owner_email);
            $('#autocompleteSex').val(ui.item.sex);

            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT

Form

```
<form action="<?= base_url('scan/scanAddAnimal') ?>" name="form1" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                <?= csrf_field(); ?>

                <?php if (!empty(session()->getFlashdata('status'))) : ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-success"><?= session()->getFlashdata('status') ?></div>
                <?php endif ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Numer chipu</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="autocompleteChip" name="chip_number" placeholder="Wprowadz numer chipu psa" value="<?= set_value('chip_number'); ?>">
                    <span class="text-danger"><?= isset($validation) ? display_error($validation, 'chip_number') : ''  ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Email właściciela</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="autocompleteEmail" name="owner_email" placeholder="Wprowadz email wlasciciela" value="<?= set_value('owner_email'); ?>">
                    <span class="text-danger"><?= isset($validation) ? display_error($validation, 'owner_email') : ''  ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dogName">Imię psa</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dogName" id="autocompleteDogName" placeholder="Wpisz imię psa" value="<?= set_value('dogName'); ?>">
                    <span class="text-danger"><?= isset($validation) ? display_error($validation, 'dogName') : ''  ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="sex">Płeć psa</label>
                    <select name="sex" id="autocompleteSex" class="form-select form-select mb-3" aria-label=".form-select-lg example">
                        <option default selected value="male">Męska</option>
                        <option value="female">Żeńska</option>
                    </select>

                    <span class="text-danger"><?= isset($validation) ? display_error($validation, 'sex') : ''  ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Rasa psa</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="autocompleteBreed" name="breed" placeholder="Wprowadz rasę psa" value="<?= set_value('breed'); ?>">
                    <span class="text-danger"><?= isset($validation) ? display_error($validation, 'breed') : ''  ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Rok urodzenia psa</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="autocompleteBirthyear" name="birthyear" placeholder="Wprowadz rok urodzenia psa" value="<?= set_value('birthyear'); ?>">
                    <span class="text-danger"><?= isset($validation) ? display_error($validation, 'birthyear') : ''  ?></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Dodaj zwierzaka" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                </div>
                <br>
            </form>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241219/discussion-on-question-by-piotr-pindel-ci4-form-with-jquery-refresh-instead-of-s).